# / was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am getting "/ was unexpected at this time." while using the below for loop for some cases only.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%m in (file.txt) do (
    echo Inside Loop
    echo %%m
)
```

I'm calling this batch file from another batch file in a loop. So every time, the content of the file.txt to be changed.

Is content of the file is a problem?

This is the full script:

```
echo off
SET FileName=%2
SET NUM=%3
:label
echo.
echo Parsing file.txt file
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%m in (file.txt) do (     
    echo Inside Loop
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo %%n
    SET str=%%m     
    SET "Number=!str::="^&REM #!
    IF "!NUM!"=="" SET NUM="!number!"       
    if !number! GEQ !NUM! (
        if /I not "!str:(ind)=!"=="!str!" (
                echo It contains IND
        ) else >>"!FileName!" echo %1;!str!

    echo %%n>Label_Name.txt
    goto label 
    )
    endlocal
)
:end
```

Comment: This can't be the code causing the error. The content can't trigger any error in this part of the code.

Comment: have you cygwin installed?

Comment: @Dewfy. no cygwin not installed

Answer (score 1):

Without any idication of the contents of your file or the parameters which which you're executing this batch, it's pure guesswork, but I suspect this line:

```
IF "!NUM!"=="" SET NUM="!number!"
```

which will set `NUM` to a quoted value.

Possibly better code would be

```
if not defined num set "num=!number!"
```

but also - you are using a `GOTO label` within a `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` which AFAIAA does NOT terminate the `LOCAL` environment, hence all processing therafter would be with the `SETLOCAL` and `delayedexpansion` in effect. Possible to re-execute the `SETLOCAL Enable...` multiple times, building greater and greater depth of local environment.... Best fixed IMHO.

Comment: It's correct, the multiple `Setlocal` will result in an overflow error

Comment: sorry The parameters are,
   %1 : svn://10.0.9.68:6140/Projects/W83627(HFG)/,
   %2 : Tempfile.txt,
   %3 : 956.
and if i comment  ") else >>!FileName! echo %1;!str!" this line. its working... i don't know why

Comment: That's understandable. A closing-parenthesis needs to be escaped if it's not related to the syntax of a command - so `(ind)` may have its closing parenthesis interpreted as the end of the `do (` for instance. Try `^)` in this situation, which says 'literal, not special meaning of ")"` Nevertheless, the `SETLOCAL` problem I mentioned needs to be fixed. Best to `EDIT` the new data (parameters) into your question, where they're easier to associate and can be better formatted. Also be an idea to paste a sample of `file.txt` - say around where the processing-problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%m in (file.txt) do (
    set "line=%%m"
    echo Inside Loop
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo !line!
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> for some cases only

It might be helpful to know more about just what those cases are.  Without further details, the question (in its current form) is highly prone to answers that involve speculation.

Here's one, for example:

If you type FOR /?, you will find that /F is described  under the section that says:

> If Command Extensions are enabled, the following additional
> forms of the FOR command are supported:

According to [CMD documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true), running CMD /E:ON will enable command line extensions.  Then, [third party documentation](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/how-do-i-enabledisable-command-extensions) notes that running CMD /Y can be used to disable the command extensions from within CMD (and CMD /X can be used to re-enable).

So if you find that running a batch file works in some cases, but "FOR /F" doesn't seem to recognize the option in other cases, the problem might not be caused by the actual source code that you're quoting.  The problem might be caused by the environment that is running the code.